# TypeError: props.users is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to send users as a prop to another page i.e. table.js using BrowserRoute. But it shows "props.users is undefined" and also it says 'addUser' is assigned a value but never used

//app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Components/Layout/Navbar";
import Table from "./Components/pages/Table";
import Home from "./Components/pages/Home";
import About from "./Components/pages/About";

const App = () => {
    const usersData = [
        { id: 1, name: "John", username: "floppydiskette" },
        { id: 2, name: "Brooke", username: "siliconeidolon" },
        { id: 3, name: "Sia", username: "benisphere" }
    ];

    const [users, setUsers] = useState(usersData);

    const addUser = user => {
        user.id = users.length + 1;
        setUsers([...users, user]);
    };

    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={addUser => <Home {...addUser} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/Table" render={users => <Table {...users} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

//table.js

```
import React from "react";

const Table = props => (
    <table className="v_artist ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.users.length > 0 ? (
                props.users.map(user => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={user.id}>
                            <td>{user.name}</td>
                            <td>{user.data}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className="button muted-button">Edit</button>
                                <button className="button muted-button">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan={3}>No users</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);

export default Table;
```

The table needs to have data viewed.and while I add the data in the form, the data should be viewed in the table. Basically, I am trying to do CRUD operation , each operation in different page.

Answer (score 1):

```
render={users => <Table {...users} />}
```

This `users` variable is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable created by `const [users, setUsers] = useState(usersData);`. So the users in your state is not being passed to the table at all, and all that's being passed down is the props from the router. I'd rename this to something more representative, and then also add in the code to pass the users:

```
render={routeProps => <Table {...routeProps} users={users} />}
```

As for addUser, you've got the same issue: You're shadowing the variable you care about, and thus not using it.

```
render={routeProps => <Home {...routeProps} addUser={addUser}/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sharing the `users` variable but instead spreading it. This means you're taking all of its elements and making them available as separate elements.

I believe what you're looking for here is:

```
<Table users={users} />
```

instead of

```
<Table {...users} />
```